# Android Medical App

Tags: android, sql

Im working on a medical app with Android and Eclipse, basically I have forms that someone can fill out on the app I want the information from the forms to be sent to a another database which i have set up on another PC. Im using wamp as my server.So do i firstly make an sql database on my app or is there a way to send the info directly to the database on another computer. Ive looked into it but im finding it confusing. If anyone could point me in the right direction im just beginning android apps and trying to teach myself. Even an overview of what exactly should be done then I can look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to write your values to a Mysql database through php get variables; e.g. run a url in background, which contains all of values, then retrieve them through php get variable, and insert into database using script on url that you've run.

Comment: Thanks for your help, ive set up an sql database on my other pc,so when I imput the information on my app its saved to an sql lite database on the app its getting it from the app to the other database thats my problem sorry im only new to this and a lil confused!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to directly access a remote database depending on the set up and nature of the remote DBMS but this is not generally considered a good idea in your context because it allows much more access than is really needed from a security point of view and a lot of overhead from a performance point of view for such a light task.

Generally you would submit this information to code running on the server in a similar manner to a web form posting information or sending an ajax request and get some meaningful response from the server as to the success of the operation.

On the server side you obviously need the server language/technology of your choice to process and act on these requests (and update the database which is local to the server code)- if you have no idea how to do this php is a fairly easy place to start.

Comment: Thanks a million for this very helpful, ive a lil bit of php knowledge alright so thats how il go about it! thank you all for your help :))